# Long division into a column

Tags: java

I need to make an example of long division as in the picture, I have already calculated the numbers, now I need to make a conclusion as in the picture, I do not understand how to do it.

Here's what I have at the moment

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Division {
    private int divisor;
    private int divident;
    private int quotient;
    private LinkedList<Integer> blackNumbersList;
    private LinkedList<Integer> greenNumbers;

    public Division(int divisor, int divident) {
        this.divisor = divisor;
        this.divident = divident;
        calculateAnswer();
    }

    private void calculateAnswer() {
        if (divisor == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divisor cannot be 0, division by zero");
        }
        quotient = divident / divisor;

        LinkedList<Integer> digitsOfQoutient = getListOfDigits(quotient);// Остача
        LinkedList<Integer> greenNumbers = new LinkedList<>();// Массив зберіганя зелених чисел

        for (int digit : digitsOfQoutient) {
            int subtractionResult = digit * divisor;
            greenNumbers.add(subtractionResult);
        }
        LinkedList<Integer> dividentArray = getListOfDigits(divident);// Ділене
        LinkedList<Integer> blackNumbersList = new LinkedList<>();// Массив зберіганя чорних чисел

        int currentDivident = dividentArray.removeFirst();// перша цифра діленого (m)
        int currentGreenNumber = greenNumbers.get(0);// перша цифра зеленого масива(s)

        while (currentDivident < currentGreenNumber) {
            currentDivident = currentDivident * 10 + dividentArray.removeFirst();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dividentArray.size(); i++) {
            currentDivident = (currentDivident - greenNumbers.get(i)) * 10 + dividentArray.get(i);
            blackNumbersList.add(currentDivident);

        }

    }

    public LinkedList<Integer> getListOfDigits(int number) {
        LinkedList<Integer> digits = new LinkedList<>();

        while (number > 0) {
            digits.push(number % 10);
            number /= 10;
        }
        return digits;
    }

    public String getDivisionView() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(divident);
        sb.append("|");
        sb.append(divisor);
        sb.append("___\n");
        sb.append(getSpaces(8));
        sb.append("  |");
        sb.append(quotient);
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("\n");

        for (Integer j : blackNumbersList) {
            for (Integer i : greenNumbers) {
                System.out.println(blackNumbersList + "\n" + "-" + greenNumbers);

            }

        }
        return sb.toString();

    }

    private String getSpaces(int count) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the picture you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).